# About Object detection tensorflow . help me please

Tags: pip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Object_Detection_WebCam.py", line 17, in 
    from utils import label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Comment: Ya si Majdi, a3mel talla 3la [lien hedha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46497701/8128190) 
fi Askubuntu, manahabtou ken les questions illi 3and'hom 3ale9a b Ubuntu, idha 3andek question filprogrammation, chouf [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: It could be that your object_detection folder is not on your path, so python does not know where to look for the files.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: yes it worked :)